# How do I access RACF user profile information?

Tags: delphi, racf

How do I access information (specifically, password expiry date) from a Resource Access Control Facility user profile?

Comment: If IBM publishes an API for accessing it, you can most likely write a Delphi interface (wrapper) for that interface. If someone has done so already, you should be able to find it via Google or Bing. There's nothing built in to Delphi to do so.

Comment: thanks for your answer ken.. If IBM have api and delphi do not have classes to support that, is this possible to implement it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible if they have a published API that's callable from C or accessible through COM interfaces. (I said that in the first sentence of my previous comment.) If the API is only available through Java, there are probably ways to still use it in Delphi (search for `JNI Delphi` on Google/Bing, IIRC).

Comment: A deleted answer mentions a Java solution. You can wrap Java in Delphi using JNI.

Answer (score 0):

The TSO command LISTUSER will give you the user's password date (in YY.DDD format) and the password interval (how many days old a password needs to be in order to be expired). You'd need to compare those with today's date.

There's a Redbook, https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247610.pdf, that talks about how to do Java Security with z/OS and that goes into some detail about it. There looks like a class, com.ibm.os390.security.PlatformUser, but that only lets you change the password, or query if you're in a group.